# How do I create a variable in SAS that satisfies certain conditions

Tags: sas

I want to create a variable in SAS that satisfies certain conditions

The variable defines a group 'definitive RT'

if a case got 5 weeks of radiation therapy then they are included. They also cannot have surgery, chemotherapy or any other treatment.

How do I tell sas to make a group which got radiation for at least 5 weeks and no other treatment?

What kind of statement would this be ?

Comment: It's likely not a single statement and it also depends on your data structure. If you all have the information in a single row versus having to parse through multiple rows to get at the information.

Comment: Right now, the question is too broad. If you provide sample data, what you expect as output and anything you've tried you're more likely to get a useful answer.